# Compare Uml Class Diagram

Tags: java, uml, composition

I have a question about relationships in uml diagrams.

Option 1:
[image: Views 1]

Option 2:
[image: Views 2]

My question is what is the difference between these two notations? Which one is right?

Comment: based off how much information is given it is hard to tell which is right.  Option 1 is just combination of two relationships composition and association. Teacher teaches student is association and the relationship between student and grades is composition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012322/what-is-navigability-in-uml-diagrams